# spinner data dependent in android

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

got problem

Have 2 spinner on layout and wanna get dependence of this spinner
Structure

```
String[] main={"Moscov","LosAngeles","Pekin"};
String[] one={"1","2","3","4"};
String[] two={"2","2","5","8"};
String[] tree={"5","7","3","2"};
```

Create first adapter for first spinner with main array.
And dependently for item choice must crete adapter with array which depend of choice 
If item 1 then adapter with array one, if item 2 then array two

Comment: Did you got your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will create your `spinner` and just set the `Adapter` for the second `spinner` according to the selection using `onItemSelected` on the first `Spinner`. Something like

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View view, int position,long arg3)
{
        TextView tv = (TextView)view;  // convert the view to TextView
        String selected = tv.getText().toString();
        if (selected.equals("Moscov"))
        {
            // set the Adapter here with the first set of values
        }
        else if(selected.equals("LosAngeles"))
        {
            // set the Adapter here with the second set of values
        }
        else
        {
            // set the Adapter here with the third set of values
        }
}
```

You also could use the `position` which may be more scalable if you put your `String Arrays` into an `ArrayList`.

Comment: If this works for you then please click the check mark next to the answer :)

Comment: yep)it's nice))but this is example, and i have 85 arrays =)
end wanna make more automatically this process

Comment: Then I would  put all of your `Arrays` in an `ArrayList` and use the `position` parameter in `onItemSelected` to get the appropriate `Array` from your `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View view, int position,long arg3)
{

      switch(position) 
       { 
         case : 0;
       // called first array
        break;

       case : 1;
      // called second array
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this code snippet , in this values of spinner 2 is dependent on spinner 1

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Spinner s1,s2;
Button btn;
String s;
TextView tv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adap1,adap2,adap3; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    s1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);


    String[] v1=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.c1);
    String[] v2=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.c2);
    String[] v3=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.c3);

    adap1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, v1);
    adap2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, v2);
    adap3=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, v3);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public class ItemSelectedListenerr implements OnItemSelectedListener  {

    String[] v=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.c1);
    public String s;
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        s=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
        if(arg2==0)
        {
            s2.setAdapter(adap1);
        }
        if(arg2==1)
        {
            s2.setAdapter(adap2);
        }
        if(arg2==2)
        {
            s2.setAdapter(adap3);
        }

        tv.setText(s);
        Log.i("hahaha", "item selected is"+s);

    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

}
```

I hope this will help you out. :)